# Laravel Relationship between two tables error after submitting the first post

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image',
        'genders_id',
        'categories_id',
        'sizes_id',
        'price'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id');
    }

    public function gender()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Gender::class, 'id');
    }

    public function size()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Size::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

index.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <td><img src="{{ url('storage/'. $post->image) }}" width="100" height="50"></td>
    <td>{{ $post->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $post->size->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $post->category->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $post->gender->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $post->price }} $</td>
    <td></td>
    </tbody>
@endforeach
```

Posts table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('genders_id');
        $table->string('sizes_id');
        $table->string('categories_id');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

PostsController:

```
public function store(PostValidation $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image')->store('image');

    Post::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'image' => $image,
        'genders_id' => $request->gender,
        'categories_id' => $request->categories,
        'sizes_id' => $request->size,
        'price' => $request->price
    ]);

    return redirect(route('post.index'));
}
```

The issue is `{{ $post->size->name }}` `{{ $post->gender->name }}` `{{ $post->category->name }}` works after my first post, whenever I add a second post it gives me the following error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PracticeOnly\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php) 
>   {{ $post->size->name }}

Comment: Isn't a post supposed to "belong to" a category? I see you're doing it the other way around, is that intended?

Comment: oh yeah, corrected it but it didnt change the outcome

Comment: I think that the problem is that `sizes_id`, `genders_id` and `categories_id` are `null` for the second post so you cannot call the relationship because they will return `null`, so you are essentially doing `{{ $post->null->name }}` atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your model like following, you mixed up the order of parameters in `hasOne()` :

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'image',
        'genders_id',
        'categories_id',
        'sizes_id',
        'price'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::class,'categories_id');
    }

    public function gender()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Gender::class,'genders_id');
    }

    public function size()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Size::class,'sizes_id');
    }
}
```

The standard naming scheme for 1 to many relation is singular column names:

```
        'genders_id' => 'gender_id'
        'categories_id' => 'category_id'
        'sizes_id' => 'size_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan tinker` find your Post via `$post = Post::find({{id}})` and then try and access its size property via `$size = $post->size`.

You should receive `null`, i.e. your Post/Size models relationship was never made.

Once that is confirmed, run `$post->size_id` to check whether this was even set in the request, if not you are not passing the size property in your request properly.

Otherwise, I would suggest you check the foreign keys in your relationships match your table names (especially in `size`), you may have overwritten the table name in the Model using the `$table` property in the Size class.

Comment: Tried ur first and third point! it both gave null!, i have shared the models, it seems fine to me!

Comment: Could you share your migration and Model for the Size class please.